# Вставить <span> в li через метод insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, ul, span

Судя по всему не проходит проверка

```
if (event.target.tagName != "SPAN") return;
```

видимо `spanы` не проставляются...

```js
let ul = document.getElementById("tree");
let lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let li of lis) {

  li.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<span>");
  li.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "</span>");

}

ul.onclick = function() {


  if (event.target.tagName != "SPAN") return;

  let li = event.target.closest("li");

  for (let child of li.children) {
    child.hidden = (child.hidden == true) ? "" : true;
  }

}
```

```html
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
  <li>Животные
    <ul>
      <li>Млекопитающие
        <ul>
          <li>Коровы</li>
          <li>Ослы</li>
          <li>Собаки</li>
          <li>Тигры</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Другие
        <ul>
          <li>Змеи</li>
          <li>Птицы</li>
          <li>Ящерицы</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Рыбы
    <ul>
      <li>Аквариумные
        <ul>
          <li>Гуппи</li>
          <li>Скалярии</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Морские
        <ul>
          <li>Морская форель</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Он вставляет законченный кусок разметки, а не заставляет перепарсить все внутренности.

Comment: Перед условием `console.log(event.target.tagName);`  вставь эту строку и глянь, что получишь в ответ...

Comment: @Qwertiy и что это означает? Перефразируйте, пожалуйста